# Wordpress Running slowly

Tags: wordpress

My wordpress site has suddenly started to run stupidly slowly and the only thing that has changed is the header of the site. I placed in a new photo slider and just moved the twitter feed. So i thought it would have something to do with this but the speed of the site is still slow when i disabled them both.

Which makes me think that it is a problem with wordpress or that i've taken something out of the header that i wasnt meant to.

link to the site: www.finderskeepersuk.com

Any help would be brilliant

Thanks

Comment: try without the header, what will happen..

Comment: I think this question doesn't belong here, and also tell us what have you tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Network tab on Chrome's inspector & [Pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/J0jarkAFx/www.finderskeepersuk.com), the majority of your loading time is waiting for your server to respond. Could just be extra latency from accessing a UK host from the US, or your server might be overloaded with a zillion other sites.

Try tinkering around with the [W3 Total Cache plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/), but if that doesn't help you might need to call your host, upgrade to a better server, or change hosts.

Also: You're loading jquery twice.